# Is it possible to check if a specific "TAB" in TabWidget is visible in current View or not?

Tags: android, view, tabs, tabwidget, horizontalscrollview

I have a `TabWidget` with 5 tabs in it. **Tabs** : "One","Two","Three","Four","Five". The `TabHost` is in a `HorizontalScrollView`. Now I've one arrow (< and >) each on each side of the `TabWidget` to indicate that there are more tabs in that direction(which are currently not visible in view).

Now what I want to do is, if the first tab is not visible(**in current view**) then the arrow to left (<) should be visible and if the last tab is not visible(**in current view**) then the arrow to right should be visible and if both tabs are not visible(**in current view**) then both arrows should be visible. I tried doing it with:

```
if (horizontablscrollview.getLeft == 0)
{
   arrowRight.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE)
   arrowLeft.setVisiblity(View.INVISIBLE)
}
else if( horizontablscrollview.getRight == 0)
{
   arrowLeft.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE)
   arrowRight.setVisiblity(View.INVISIBLE)
}

else if ( horizontablscrollview.getRight == 0 && horizontablscrollview.getLeft == 0)
{
    arrowRight.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE)
    arrowLeft.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE)
}
```

But this doesn't work, my both tabs are invisible in the start:

**my xml looks like this..**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RL_Header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dip"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_Home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_home"
            android:onClick="onHomeButtonClick"
            android:src="@drawable/title_home" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_about"
            android:onClick="onClickAbout"
            android:src="@drawable/title_about" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/FL_Tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/RL_Header" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/FL_Tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/RL_Header" >

        <TabHost
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#ffffff" >

                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/arrow_left"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/i_button"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>            

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_tabs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/arrow_left"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/i_button"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:visibility="invisible"/>

                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/arrow_Right"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/i_button"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:visibility="invisible"/>                    

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/my_scrollView"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    android:scrollbars="none" 
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/arrow_left"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrow_Right">

                    <TabWidget
                        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:tabStripEnabled="true"/>
                </HorizontalScrollView>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="65dip" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/myTabContent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dip" >

                    <TableLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tabSubs"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#ffffff"
                        android:shrinkColumns="*"
                        android:stretchColumns="*" >

                        <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/btntestno1"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:padding="20dip"
                                android:text="Test 1"
                                android:textColor="#000000" />

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/btntestno2"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:padding="20dip"
                                android:text="Test 2"
                                android:textColor="#000000" />
                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/btntestno3"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:padding="20dip"
                                android:text="Test 3"
                                android:textColor="#000000" />

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/btntestno4"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:padding="20dip"
                                android:text="Test 4"
                                android:textColor="#000000" />
                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/btntestno5"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:padding="20dip"
                                android:text="Test 5"
                                android:textColor="#000000" />

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/btntestno6"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:padding="20dip"
                                android:text="Test 6"
                                android:textColor="#000000" />
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </TabHost>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to make you own `HorizontalScrollView` class and show the `ImageViews` based on the scroll(although I didn't tested that much the code below should work). Your layout will look like this:

```
//...
           <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_tabs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/arrow_left"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/i_button"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:visibility="gone"/>

                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/arrow_Right"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/i_button"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        />                    

                <com.your.package.here.SpecialScroll
                    android:id="@+id/my_scrollView"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    android:scrollbars="none" >

                    <TabWidget
                        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:tabStripEnabled="true"/>
                </com.your.package.here.SpecialScroll>
            </RelativeLayout>

//...
```

The `SpecialScroll` class will look like this:

```
public class SpecialScroll extends HorizontalScrollView {

    public interface PositionListener {

        public void onLeftArrowRequired(boolean required);

        public void onRightArrowRequired(boolean required);

        public View implementScrolledView();
    }

    private PositionListener listener;

    public void setPositionListener(PositionListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public SpecialScroll(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SpecialScroll(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public SpecialScroll(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        if (l == 0) {
            listener.onLeftArrowRequired(false);
        } else {
            listener.onLeftArrowRequired(true);
        }
        View v = listener.implementScrolledView();
        Rect r = new Rect();
        v.getDrawingRect(r);
        if ((r.width() - l) == getWidth()) {
            listener.onRightArrowRequired(false);
        } else {
            listener.onRightArrowRequired(true);
        }

    }

}
```

Then in your activity's `onCreate` method you'll do:

```
SpecialScroll hsv = (SpecialScroll) findViewById(R.id.my_scrollView);
hsv.setPositionListener(this); // I made the activity implement the SpecialScroll.PositionListener interface
```

and the activity's implementation of the `PositionListener` interface is:

```
@Override
    public void onLeftArrowRequired(boolean required) {
        if (required) {
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.arrow_left))
                    .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.arrow_left))
                    .setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRightArrowRequired(boolean required) {
        if (required) {
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.arrow_right))
                    .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.arrow_right))
                    .setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View implementScrolledView() {
        return findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);
    }
```

Comment: Hey man the code you posted here is close to what i want but it doesnt work as intented. I am sorta new to this and don't know how to manipulate the code so it works correctly. It's my request if you could check it out to get it working. I would be greatly thankful. And sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @user1395649 You should mention how my code works now and how you wanted to work instead. I can't read minds:)

Comment: lol sorry for that,what happens is,when i scroll extreme right,the left arrow(which is supposed to become visible) becomes invisible and the right (which should be gone) stays there. The center portion (where both the arrows should become visible) works perfectly. Now when i scroll the view to extreme LEFT from RIGHT,the right and the left both arrows just stay there(where as the left should be gone when we're at extreme left). I hope i explained this correctly,if not i am here. Thanks for quick reply man (:

Comment: @user1395649 I've retested my code and it works. Maybe you didn't implement the `SpecialScroll.PositionListener` interface correct? Anyway I've put the project that I used for testing here( https://gist.github.com/2952671 ) to see how it works, see if this works and if it does make the proper adjustement to your code.

Comment: oh okay i'll check it and see what i did wrong,thank you so much and sorry for the trouble

Comment: Thanks man it worked,i didnt implement the listener properly,sorry for the trouble. Cheers!

Comment: @user1395649 If my answer helped you could mark it as correct with the check mark. Also you should delete the other question you posted, there is no need for duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an elegant solution, but you could display the left arrow if the x coordinate of the leftmost tab was less than zero and display the right tab if the rightmost tab's x plus its width was greater than the screen width.

Comment: The thing is if i have 3 tabs in view (4th 5th and 6th) then the arrow should be visible beside 4th tab. I just wanted to know if it is possible to know if the specific tab is visible in view,so we can set Visibility of the arrows accordingly.

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you are asking.  If the 4th, 5th and 6th tabs are visible, then my suggestion would work.  You would know that a left arrow is required.  Are you tying the arrows to the edges of the screen, or on the buttons specifically?  If they are tied to the screen, then I see no concern.

Comment: could u please check my answer below,was not able to post my code with my comment here. Sorry for that.