# How to show half item in scrollview which indicate more products in scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview

I used Horizontal scroll view in which I add 'Child View'. But on HZ scroll view I want to arrange child some think like, whole screen will show 3.5 child at a time or 4.5 , 5.5 depends on screen size. The half of child indicate there is more child on Scroller.

For that I used different dimensions for child view depends on density. But still their is some device which show whole child at the end of screen.

So how I can mange this on scroll view. Please guide me in right direction.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For that I used different dimensions for child view depends on
>   density. But still their is some device which show whole child at the
>   end of screen.

That will not work well in a lot of devices.
Assuming that those orange child views are all of the same width(although not that important) and you want to show half of one only when the `HorizontallScrollView` is first laid out, you could simply post a `Runnable`(in the `onCreate` method) on a view to set their widths to a proper dimension so you make the proper appearance:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle saved) {
    // ... work   
    horizontalScrollView.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                int screenWidth = dm.widthPixels;
                // based on this width, the space between the children and their
                // widths calculate new widths so you get a half clipped
                // children on the right side.
            }
        });
}
```

But, I would avoid this and simply set a much more powerful indicator on the `HorizontalScrollView`(overriding its `dispatchDraw` method and drawing something there(maybe also hiding it a bit later with a `Runnable`)) if you really want to make sure that the user sees the extra content.

Comment: Calculating Item width dynamically is it good for applications performance, because I need to add multiple HorizontalScrollView in a one verticalScrollView and every child Item size is diff for different horizontal scrollview (fix in one horizontal scrollview). Also their is no any android API which allow me to show half child in scrollView.   Also I am think about any powerful indicator suitable for my UI. Thanks.

Comment: @AmolWadekar The first sentence was a question? You can do the same thing I said for a `ScrollView`.

Comment: Can you explain me this "(overriding its dispatchDraw method and drawing something there(maybe also hiding it a bit later with a Runnable)". And yes it is question "Calculating Item width dynamically is it good for applications performance?"

Comment: @AmolWadekar There shouldn't be any performance problems because will be doing it once in the `onCreate` method when the `Activity` first starts(and you'll just make some small calculations). You can draw something(an indicator) on top of the content of the `HorizontalScrollView` in the `dispatchDraw` method if the content is bigger then the screen's width. You can also place another view on top, see this question I answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051909/is-it-possible-to-check-if-a-specific-tab-in-tabwidget-is-visible-in-current-v

Comment: Thanks Luksprog for your help, I accept your answer & try to implement in your way.

Comment: @Luksprog Hi , I am using Recycler View. You have given an example using HorizontalRecyclerView. How do I achieve same ?

Comment: @KaranSharma The principle would be the same, you would need to calculate the fixed dimension of the rows so you end up with half a view and then use that calculated dimension in the adapter's onCreateViewHolder() to update the LayoutParams of the created view with that value(don't forget to call notifydataSetChanged()). In the end I think you're looking for an introduction for the user which could be easily be done by a small animation to scroll the RecyclerView forward and back with a small amount when the app is first started.